# Using Wordpress title in external site

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a HTML/PHP website. I am including wordpress posts/pages and functions on and i am using the wordpress page title function:

```
<title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
```

If a user visits a HTML Page that does not exist as a Wordpress Post or Page the Wordpress title is showing as `Page Not Found`

how can i change it so it doesn't show page not found and so it shows another page title of just a generic title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `wp_title( '|', true, 'right' );`

to

```
 if( is_404() ) echo 'your title | ';
  else wp_title( '|', true, 'right' );
```